# Uploading files through jquery.form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, file

I've got following html doc for ajax file uploads:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#file_upload_form').ajaxForm({
               success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                 if (data.redirect)
                    window.location.replace(data.redirect);
                 else
                    alert(data.text);
               },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("unexpected error: " + textStatus);
               },
               dataType: "json",
           });
       });  
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <form id="file_upload_form" action="http://apddr/pl/administration/test/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <table class="grey" id="file_table"> 
                <tr> 
                    <th colspan="2"> 
                        Add file
                    </th> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 10em;" class="strong"><label for="id_file">File name:</label></td> 
                    <td> 
                        <input type="file" name="file" size="50" id="id_file" style="background-color: initial;"/><br /> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td class="strong"> 
                        <label for="id_language">Choose lang:</label> 
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        <select id="id_language" name="language"> 
                            <option value="">-- no language --</option> 
                            <option value="ANG">english</option> 
                            <option value="NIE">german</option> 
                        </select> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td class="strong"><label for="id_description">Description:</label></td> 
                    <td> 
                        <input class="text" type="text" name="description" maxlength="300" id="id_description" style="width: 100%;"/><br /> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td class="strong"></td> 
                    <td class="strong" style="text-align: right"> 
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="addFile" value="Send" /> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Calling http://apddr/pl/administration/test/ returns application/json '{'text': 'test'}'.

Under Chromium alert("unexpected error: " + textStatus); line is called with textStatus='aborted' what is unwanted, but firefox is downloading this JSON. In addition, in firebug console it instantly prints:

```
[jquery.form] state = uninitialized
```

What am I doing wrong? Help!

**UPDATE:**

OK it appears that transfers are managed by django module - filetransfers (server side), so if I try to upload using filetransfers handler (another action link) It works - but only under Chromium. Firefox still crashes

**UPDATE2:**

It seems that someone crossed this problem: http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/01/get-json-data-response-with-jquery-form.html

**UPDATE3:**
Solution above works!

Comment: just a guess...write your script at last...means after your html.

Comment: It's called after document is ready

Comment: You have an extra ',' after `dataType: "json"`

Comment: yeah, but it changes nothing.

Comment: I got `[jquery.form] state = uninitialized` error due to my implementation: 
`$('#form_id').ajaxForm({ iframe: true, success: function (result) { $('#divid').html(result); }); `

the "#divid" div where I was placing the results had a missing/incorrect id.

Answer (score 0):

*GitHub solution:* [never ending loop with blank file input (patch included)](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/113)

As per [malsup](https://github.com/malsup) comment

```
Added proposed fix to v2.91.
```

Download [jQuery.form.js version 3.50](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malsup/form/master/jquery.form.js)

Problem solved for me.